# Query by attributes of referenced entity in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I have two collections in RavenDB: one for products and another for pricing strategies for each product. Each pricing strategy references a single product by product ID. For example, a product may look like this:

```
products/1
{
 "Brand":"Dewalt",
 "Model":"ABC123",
 "Category":"Tools"  
}
```

and a strategy may look like this:

```
strategies/1
{
 "ProductId":"products/1",
 "PriceCalculation":{
   "$type":"...",
   "Margin":0.2
 }
}
```

I need to be able to query strategies by their attributes but also by the attributes of the associated products. For example - return all strategies with a specific margin where the product is in a specific category. If product data was denormalized and stored with the strategy then I could simply add product attributes to the index. Is there a way to do this without denormalization?

I understand that the Include method allows the inclusion of referenced entities in the result set so that they don't have to be loaded, but it doesn't support *querying* on the included entity. The same is true for live projections - they allow including referenced entities in the result set but don't support *querying* by attributes of the referenced entity.

I can run two queries across two indexes - one for strategies and another for products and then join the two result sets on product ID. The problem in this case is that the product collection may not always be synchronized with the set of products referenced by strategies. More specifically, the products collection may contain more products than are referenced by strategies and so the query may return products which don't have a pricing strategy and therefore can't be joined to a strategy all while taking up a position in the result set.

What could work is if I could resolve the referenced entity in the Map function and then include attributed of referenced entity in the index.

**EDIT**
I seem to be looking for this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/k3qvdEb870U/95OWtjL3U3YJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I've found that the best way to do this is with a [Multi-Maps / Reduce Index](http://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes). Two map functions are specified, one for products and another for strategies. The reduce function groups the two result sets by product ID and then merges in the output. The declaration of this index is a bit awkward because you have to ensure that the shape of the results match - it would be nice if Raven did this automatically with an option to override. Also merging results in the reduce function is awkward because you have to select a value from the group which comes from the desired map function. Overall though, a multi-maps / reduce index allows the joining of distinct collections into a single indexed projection.